# onload call to getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I looked and didn't find the case I have here -- a lot of the prior answers said 'wait for the 'onload' to call getElementById' but that's what I started with and it doesn't work -- getElementById returns null in this code in my index.php file:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkPwd()
    {
        var thePwd = document.getElementById("theUsersPassword");
        alert("the var thePwd is: " + thePwd);

    }
</script>        
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Beta:</title>
</head>

<body onload="checkPwd()">

  <form method="post"  action="index.php">
    Beta: <input name="theUsersPassword" type="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alert statement should be `alert("the var thePwd is: " + thePwd.value);`

Comment: okay now thePwd is HTMLInputElement but alert("The password's value entered was " + thePwd.value) and alert("The password's innerHTML entered was " + thePwd.innerHTML) are both empty after I type 'foo' in the password field -- is my form's post wiping out the contents somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getElementById get an element by ID not by name. You must change

```
<input name="theUsersPassword" type="password">
```

to

```
<input name="theUsersPassword" id="theUsersPassword" type="password" />
```

Comment: Francis if that photo of the guy in the tie is you, that looks exactly I mean *exactly* like me age 17.  I mean exactly.  I guess the statistical chance of having zero people who look exactly like me, and have them be alive during my lifetime, is probably small.  However, the probability of having someone who has identical facial bone structure, complexion and hair/eye color -- alive during my lifetime -- and responding to a question I pose on stackoverflow -- is about zero.  Sorry for going off there.  Both you guys solved my code issue and I gave up arrows to both but you answered first

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up `name` and `id`

**Edit:**

In other words, you need to change

```
<input name="theUsersPassword" type="password">
```

to

```
<input name="theUsersPassword" id="theUsersPassword" type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. `getElementById` returned an object not a value.

JavaScript

```
function checkPwd()
{
    var thePwd = document.getElementById("theUsersPassword").value;
    alert("the var thePwd is: " + thePwd);

}
```

Html

```
<input name="theUsersPassword"  id="theUsersPassword"  type="password">
```

Comment: I used the following but the alert says thePwd is blank                   var thePwd = document.getElementById("theUsersPassword").value;
            alert("the var thePwd is: " + thePwd);

Comment: <input id="theUsersPassword" name="usersPassword" type="password"><br/> is the input tag, I think I'm using getElementById correctly now, why does the form post erase the 'value' of the password?